# seaborn.catplot got ValueError when changing the value for x and y

Tags: python, matplotlib, plot, seaborn

I'm writing a python script to plot how status fluctuate between s0 and s2 as time going on. My input look like this:

```
timestamp|servo

0|s0

1|s0

2|s2

3|s0

4|s2

5|s0

6|s0
```

The way I wrote my input csv is like this:

```
headers = ['timestamp', 'servo']
with open(('/home/ray/proj/5th_output/asym/slave/test/' + str(testname) + '.csv'), 'w', newline='') as csvfile:
    spamwriter = csv.DictWriter(csvfile, fieldnames=headers, delimiter='|')
    spamwriter.writeheader()

    for i in range(0, len(eachservo)):
        row = {'timestamp': str(ts[i]), 'servo': eachservo[i]}
        spamwriter.writerow(row)
```

The way I plot my csv input is like:

```
    for csvname in glob.glob(os.path.join(path, '*.csv')):
        readcsv = pd.read_csv(csvname)
        sns.set(style="ticks")
        g = sns.catplot(x=timestamp, y=servo, data=readcsv)
```

The plot I got is correct in terms of the content, but the title of x and y is completely messed up:
[image]

However, if I change `sns.catplot(x=timestamp, y=servo, data=readcsv)`
to `sns.catplot(x='timestamp', y='servo', data=readcsv)`, it will report a valueError saying `ValueError: Could not interpret input 'timestamp'`, so I'm stucking with using two lists as parameter for catplot.

What mistake am I making here? Is it the way I wrote csv causing this issue or I miss some catplot argument?

**EDIT:**

I found where my problem is, it's because I use csv.DoctWriter to write a csv and then panda for reading it. I solved it by replacing csv.DoctWriter with pandas `to_csv`.

Comment: Try putting `delimiter="|"` in the `pd.read_csv` though I doubt that's the main problem here.

Comment: @adch Thank you a lot for the reply, I found where my problem is.

Comment: Instead of editing the answer into the question, post an actual answer instead. See [Can I answer my own question?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/self-answer). You could also elaborate on your answer, describe how you found the solution.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found where my problem is, it's because I use `csv.DoctWriter` to write a csv and then panda for reading it. I solved it by replacing `csv.DoctWriter` with pandas `to_csv`.

By using `csv.DoctWriter` with `delimiterto = '|'` write and use `pd.read_csv`, the column in the csv will be read as `timestamp|servo` instead of `timestamp` and `servo`.